# Launch wpf windows app from chrome and firefox

Tags: c#, wpf, google-chrome, firefox, uri

I have a windows desktop app. When i type myapp:// in internet explorer it asks me if i want to open the same program on my computer. When i press OK, it launches my application. I have of course configured this in my application. The application can also be launched from the command line using myapp://.

```
If args.Startswith("myapp://")
{ 
app.start();
}
```

I want to achieve the same behavior on chrome and firefox. 
I have tried to google this, and found suggestions of using web+.

Appreciate suggestions !